# Calculating the inverse of f(x)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $$f(x)=\frac{2x+p}{x-1}$$
>   where $x ≠ 1$ and $p$ is a constant.
>
> 1. Determine the inverse of $f(x)$.
> 2. If $f^{-1}(8)=5$, find the value of $p$.

Can someone explain to me, with simple steps, how this can be calculated?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$y = \frac{2x+p}{x-1}.$$ If we cross multiply, we have that $$yx-y = 2x+p.$$ By collecting like terms, we have that $$x(y-2) = p+y.$$ Then you see that $$ x = \frac{p+y}{y-2}.$$ Thus, the inverse function that you want is $$f^{-1}(x) = \frac{p+x}{x-2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$y = f(x)\\
f^{-1}(y) = x$

$y = \frac {2x+p}{x-1}$

Isolate $x.$

$y(x-1) = 2x+p\\
xy - 2x = p+y\\
x(y - 2) = p+y\\
x = \frac {p+y}{y-2}\\
$

$f^{-1}(y) =  \frac {p+y}{y-2}\\
f^{-1}(8) =  \frac {p+8}{8-2} = 5$

and solve for $p.$